# Windows 7 Can't see harddrive, but Device Manager does...?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I just upgraded to Windows 7.

I have an old western Digital Hard drive that is 120GB's of Data.  I have everything that my life holds digitally dear on it.  I can't find the Driver for it on Western Digital and Well my Windows 7 Device manager sees it, but Windows 7 does not.  I have tried everything that comes to mind, wondering if there is any hack now that I can at least get my data off of this drive.

The Model is:

WDC WD1200JB-75CRA0 ATA Device

BTW, I am not going to give up on this.  Please help!!!

Side Note: I still have the old operating system files on my hard drive.  If anyone can point me to where the driver might be hidden on the old windows OS??

Comment: when you look in the device manager does it give the yellow ? indicating the lack of driver? also what is the model of the WD hard drive.  Is it IDE or SATA?

Comment: No Yellow question mark.  Windows 7 sees it there in the Device manager, but in Windows Explorer it doesn't show.  Its on the IDE line.  It also gives a driver for it, but nothing in Explorer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is assign a drive letter.  You should be able to do this by right clicking My Computer > Manage > Disk Management.  From there you will see your partition(s) and you simply right click > change driver letters and paths > assign a letter.

Comment: You are amazing!!! Thank you soo much.  I guess that is a place I didn't know existed yet in windows 7!!  Thank you.  Ill accept your answer once the time limit hits.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)